# How to save output expect in bash

Tags: bash, expect, cisco

I am trying to make a script to save a output of the command show version in cisco.

I need made a connection to one server for that the ssh connection, and then i have connection with the device.

In the file out.txt, I have the output of the first connection, the ssh connection, but i dont know how to save the output of the show version

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/sh
spawn ssh -l user x.x.x.x
expect "login as:"
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
expect "$\r"
send "telnet nemonic\r"
expect "$\r"
expect "login:"
send "user\r"
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
expect "*>"
send "terminal length 0\r"
send "show version \r"
expect "*>"
set results $expect_out(buffer)
set config [open out.txt w]
puts $config $results
close $config
send "exit\r"
expect eof
send  "\r"
send "exit\r"
```

Could you help me?

Best regards

Comment: You can't have two shebangs.

Comment: ^^ That being said, I _think_ `expect` would interpret the second line as comment & ignore it. Entire script is pure `expect` script.

Comment: the expect works fine, the problem is the output, just save the first connection, but if you told me, how can implement that in one line, i make it, thank you @anishsane

Answer (score 0):

I solve with

```
log_file -noappend status.txt
```

after the command show version

Thank you && Best Regards